# How to change icons above stats?

Tags: apex-legends

Whenever we are presented with either our own squad or with the current champion and their squad at least one of them has more than one icon above their stats.

**Are those icons achievements of some kind? What do they indicate and how can I change them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are badges that are freely customizable in your Legends tab.  Unlocking badges requires completing the requirements for the badge to be unlocked, which can be found by hovering over the individual badge.

Some badges are account-wide, like your player level and some event ones, like the Valentine's one, while most badges are legend-specific and thus unlocking on one legend will not unlock it on other legends.